# skype web sdk starter

Tags: web, sdk, skype

I am trying to test Skype Web SDK at my local PC.

What I did is created a html page, added SkypeBootstrap script reference to it like this:

```
<script src="https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.2.15/SkypeBootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and trying to play with the API:

```
Skype.initialize({ apiKey: 'a42fcebd-5b43-4b89-a065-74450fb91255' }, api => {
            var app = new api.application;
            app.signInManager.signIn({
                username: 'my_skype_related@login.com',
                password: 'my_skype_password'
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("signed in as", app.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
            }, err => {
                console.log("cannot sign in", err);
            });
        }, err => {
            console.log("cannot load the sdk package", err);
        });
```

app.signInManager.signIn just runs and I see that app.signInManager.state is always 'SigningIn', nothing else happens. I have looked through different articles but haven't found any simple set of prerequisites to make this thing work. I don't have anything related to Skype for business, lync server or anything else installed anywhere locally. I tried to search for and download Lync server, but even MSFT links are broken.

Is here anybody who can explain what shall I do to make the sample above run well? How can I test Skype web sdk at my local PC?

Comment: I just tried the official example at https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk. Runs forever without a feedback :-(

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?